# What Happens To Cookies When I CURL

Tags: cookies, curl

Im using curl to load content from a url but when i do the cookies from the website dont get set in my browser.

Is there a better way to open a external url with php and make getting cookies work?

By the way below is how i load the page with the curl on it maybe thats why cookies dont get set.
`<img src="http://apprevues.com/pxl.php?i=1" height="1" width="1" />`

Comment: If you're using curl to download content from an external site onto your web *server*, why would you expect cookies from that site to end up on your web *browser*? How would they get there?

Comment: i just want to use curl to open the url, my intention is not for it to do anything with server

Answer (score 2):

When requesting a web page using cURL with PHP, keep in mind the the request and response are both associated with your PHP script, which is on your server. At this point, the client's browser hasn't come into play at all.
There are methods of managing cookies using cURL (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), but for what you're describing here, the cookies need to be owned by the client's browser.

In order for cookies to be associated with the client, the request and response must also be associated with the client (i.e. the browser has to visit the url itself).

I suggest learning about [Header redirects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php); I believe that these will address your need. It simply directs the client's browser to the given url, thus associating any cookies from the site with your client's browser instead of your server.

Here is an example implementation to get you started:

```
<?php
$url = "https://google.com/";
header("Location: ".$url);
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i need to fake the referrer which is why im using CURL